# how to make a directory in wordpress accessible from the web

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working on a bit of a frankenstien wordpress site at the moment, it incorporates a few things including a different CMS that needs to be accessible from outside without WP rewriting URLs or anything.

What I want is to be able to access `domain.com/myFolder` with a browser and let it go through unmolested (and any subsequent requests to anything inside that directory).
Anything else gets the normal treatment - e.g viewing a post on `domain.com/2011-02-02/my-post` will serve up post content.

Here is the .htaccess file wordpress is currently using:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /domain.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't understand `.htaccess` in the least, so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it your real .htaccess ? Because apparently `myFolder` is outside wordpress directory, so WP should not rewrite it.

Comment: well i don't actually own domain.com lol. think I see what you mean though, please see edited version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RewriteCond to disable rewrite for myFolder :

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !^myFolder/.*
```

Or a blank RewriteRule :

```
RewriteRule ^myFolder/ - [L]
```

Insert one of these rules before `RewriteRule . /domain.com/index.php [L]`

Not sure about the path since I need more informations about your directory structure.